# Applying function across range of different columns

Tags: python, function, pandas, apply

I have a function that looks for certain strings across 2 different columns and returns the original row value if it meets the function conditions:

```
def functionator(row):
    if 'J44' in row['0_c']:
        if 'J44' in row['A0']:
            return row['0_c']
        else:
            return np.nan
    elif 'I50' in row['0_c']:
        if 'I50' in row['A0']:
            return row['0_c']
        else:
            return np.nan
    elif 'I51' in row['0_c']:
        if ('I50' or 'I51') in row['A0']:
            return row['0_c']
        else:
            return np.nan
    elif 'F03X' in row['0_c']:
        if ('F00' or 'F01' or 'F02') in row['A0']:
            return row['0_c']
        else:
            return np.nan
    elif 'N18' in row['0_c']:
        if 'N18' in row['A0']:
            return row['0_c']
        else:
            return np.nan
    else:
        return np.nan
```

`df['0_c'] = df.apply(functionator, axis=1)`

However, I want to apply this function over a range of columns, so instead of only checking it over `row['0_c']` I want to check it across `row['i_c'] for i in range(n)` and also have it check over a range of `row['Ai'] for i in range(m)`

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of code is horribly inefficient.  You should start by restructuring it to operate on vectors rather than scalars:

```
def vectorator(df, col1, col2):
    col_0_c = df[col1].str.contains
    col_A0 = df[col2].str.contains

    J44 = col_0_c('J44') & col_A0('J44')
    I50 = col_0_c('I50') & col_A0('I50')
    I51 = col_0_c('I51') & col_A0('I5[01]')
    F03X = col_0_c('F03X') & col_A0('F0[012]')
    N18 = col_0_c('N18') & col_A0('N18')

    matches = J44 | I50 | I51 | F03X | N18
    df[col1][~matches] = np.nan
```

Then it's easy to run several times:

```
for col1i in range(n):
    for col2i in range(m):
        vectorator(df, '{}_c'.format(col1i), 'A{}'.format(col2i))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Unfortunately though it seems as if the code requires that the strings e.g. 'J44' have to occur across all the A columns for it to return the string, rather than just one in the range(m) (or at least that's my limited understanding)

Comment: @Matt: Have you tried the code?  I think you may find it does what you want.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help. I did run the code but it just wasn't giving me my desired output. However, I made a small change to the code: filling in J44 = col_0_c('J44') & functools.reduce(np.logical_or, [df['A{}'.format(i)].str.startswith('J44') for i in range(m)]) instead of what you put and it seemed to work.

Comment: OK great.  Now replace `functools.reduce(np.logical_or, ...)` with `np.logical_or.reduce(...)`.  It's more efficient.

Comment: If you found this answer useful, you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome.